# Not able to create object in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am new to Django and I am struggling to create and save an object based on a model in my apps `models.py`

The code I am using:

```
def search(request):
  try:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product = request.POST.get('product')
        listed, not_listed = scrapeSellers(product)

        search = Searches(product=product,
                        no_of_sellers=len(listed),
                        valid_search=1,
                        best_price=listed[0]['cost'],
                        worst_price=listed[-1]['cost'])
        search.save()

        print(product)
        print(len(listed))
        print(listed[0]['cost'])
        print(listed[-1]['cost'])

    return render(request, 'app/search.html', {
        'listed' : listed,
        'not_listed' : not_listed,
    })

  except:
    return render(request, 'app/search.html', {})
```

And my `models.py` looks like this:

```
class Searches(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)        
   product = models.CharField(max_length=8)           
   no_of_sellers = models.IntegerField()            
   valid_search = models.BooleanField()           
   best_price = models.FloatField(blank=True)
   worst_price = models.FloatField(blank=True)
   timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Additionally, print statements that I have after `search.save()` are not executed, so it appears the object creation is failing and then not executing the rest of the function.

I am no getting any error messages in the console and nothing is happening in my Database. As far as I can see, I'm doing exactly as stated in the Django Docs example:

```
p = Person(name="Fred Flintstone", shirt_size="L")
p.save()
```

I'm using a MySQL database, Python 3.6, and Django 2.1.7.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is this code? What are `product` and `listed`?

Comment: Please show your entire view

Comment: Have updated my original post with full view. `listed` is a list of dicts (a dict for each seller that has the product advertised - includes details like their price, url to product etc). `product` is a user entered term from a form. If I take out the object create and object save, my code works exactly as I need it to.

Comment: Have u tried using Searches.objects.create() ? Or please update the question with HTML form and what is scrapeSellers(product)?

Comment: Yes I have tried Searches.objects.create(product=product etc) too and same result. scrapeSellers(product) is a function which gathers prices from each seller's website and returns a list of dicts - it works fine until I introduce the object creation and saving.

Comment: Please update your form

Comment: The obvious thing to do would seem to print out all variables that go into the creation of your `Searches` object *before* trying to create and save the object. Do all variables contain the expected data?

Comment: Hi Endre, yes they do print the correct values. Additionally, if I try to print the values before and after the creation of Searches object, the print statements only happen once?

Comment: I have solved it - my best and worst prices were formatted with '£' at the start, and I was obviously trying to save them as floats!! Thanks everyone.